# CSS - Relative Div next to fixed Div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

I am developing a responsive site to work on both mobile and desktop.  The site has a left hand menu.  In desktop mode I always want this to visible, in mobile I want it hidden by default but with a button to open it.  I effectively have 2 divs. One for the left hand menu which is fixed, the other for the remaining content which I want to be relative, when the left hand menu is not visible I want it to move to the left hand most side of the page.

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;

    max-width: 200px;    
  }

  #page-content-wrapper {
    position:relative;
    left: 0;
  }
```

The problem I have is that the page content div is always behind the left menu.  I won't it to be positioned relative to it.  I can set the left to 200px however this means when the left menu is not visible the main div still sits 200px in from the left when I want it to move to the left hand side.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keithnolan/747xyeb6/)

Comment: Can you please share in jsfiddle to check or the url?

Comment: Question updated with jsfiddle link.  What I want is when the left div is hidden the other div moves to the leftmost position

Comment: The other div is already at the leftmost position. Or if you mean _all the way_ to the left, give the body a margin of 0.

Comment: Yes, all the way to the left.  I know I can do it with Javascript however I'm trying to keep to a pure css as I'm using several media rules in my css depending on screen size

Comment: I also want the main div to be next to the left div when it is visible and not behind it as it is in my fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Relative positioning is not relative to other elements, it is relative to where the element would flow on the page. If you want your green div to always be positioned the same way next to your red div, you should either use js or put your green div inside your red div and position it absolutely 100% from the left side of the containing div.
I also changed your code so that your red div moves off screen to the left, otherwise it would hide everything it had contained in it.

```
$("#toggle").click(function (){                       
    if($("#sidebar-wrapper").css('left') == "0px"){
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").animate({left: "-200px"}, 1000);      
    }
    else{
        $("#sidebar-wrapper").animate({left: "0px"}, 1000);   
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/747xyeb6/1/)